# Setting the queue length on HP p410(i) controllers

Tags: hard-drive

The guys responsible for the DB  performance tuning asked me to change the queue depth on the two HP p410(i) controllers of my DL380 G6 server. They want me to switch it from automatic to 64. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do it.

I've tried to bring up the array config CLI and type:

```
controller slot=2 modify queuedepth=64
```

and I got back:

```
Error: This operation is not supported with the current configuration. Use the
   "show" command on devices to show additional details about the
   configuration.
```

(Same thing with the slot 0 which is the embedded controller)

Any idea ?

OS is Windows 2008 R2 (x64), the ACU CLI version is 8.50-60

Comment: What disks are you using, exact model/s ideally?

Comment: 7x72 gigs HP EH0072FAWJA (15k SAS) on controller 1.  
7x146 gigs HP EH0146FAWJB (15k SAS) on controller2.
Firmeware revison HPDD for both

Comment: did you run the command as admin, remember just being logged into the console with admin privs doesn't cut it.

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't think it patters, though